# How do I set a variable in VBA to equal the title of a workbook? And how do I allow it change based on the cell it references?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, copy-paste

I am trying to have a cell (A37) equal a variable in VBA and have that variable change which workbook it references based on Cell A37. In A37 I plan to change the name of the workbook to change which workbook it pulls data from.

Cell A37 will have the name of the workbook I want to output from, and Cell A38 will have the name of the worksheet I want to output from (within the workbook from Cell A37).

Here is the code I wrote but I keep receiving errors when I set the OPEXsht equal to a cell. (I'm very new at VBA coding)

```
Sub CellName ()
Dim OPEXwbk As String
Dim OPEXsht As String

OPEXsht = Workbooks("VBA TRIAL.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A38")

OPEXwbk = Workbooks("VBA TRIAL.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A37")

Workbooks(OPEXwbk).Sheets(OPEXsht).Range("B22").Copy

Workbooks("VBA TRIAL.xlsb").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A42").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: one does not `Set` a string.  Remove the `Set ` at the beginning of each of those lines.

Comment: That's embarrassing. Thank you for that. Do then also know if A37 has text with the name of another workbook. Why I still receive "Subscript out of Range" on the command "Copy" line of code? @ScottCraner

Comment: It means the spellings do not match.

Comment: Hm...that's odd, because they are correct. Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I mean to say, can VBA understand the text from Cell A37 and use the variable (OPEXwbk) as a substitute for actually writing the workbook's name? Thanks for the help! @ScottCraner

Comment: Is the target workbook open?  and are you using the file type extension?

Comment: Ya the target workbook is open and the file extension matches ".xlsb"...   @ScottCraner

Comment: Do you have more than 1 instance of excel running ie. is VBA TRIAL.xlsb open in a different instance to the one your macro is running in ?

Comment: I only have one workbook/version of VBA TRIAL open at one time if that's what you mean? Sorry I might be confused by your question? @CDP1802

Comment: Is this macro located in VBA TRIAL.xlsb and if so is the OPEXwbk workbook in the same folder as VBA TRIAL.xlsb ?

Comment: Yes, the Macro is located in VBA TRIAL and the OPEXwbk is in another workbook. So no they don't share the same Excel file...@CDP1802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add some error checking at each stage of the process.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CellName()

    ' This macro in VBA TRIAL.xlsb
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim sOPEXwbk As String, sOPEXsht As String
    Dim msg As String, bOK As Boolean
   
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        sOPEXwbk = .Range("A37") ' book
        sOPEXsht = .Range("A38") ' sheet
    End With
   
    ' check not blank
    If Len(sOPEXwbk) = 0 Or Len(sOPEXsht) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No workbook or worksheet configured on Sheet2 A37,A38", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
   
    ' check workbook open
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & wb.Name
        If wb.Name = sOPEXwbk Then bOK = True
    Next
   
    ' workbook not open
    If bOK = False Then
        MsgBox "'" & sOPEXwbk & "' not in list" & msg, vbCritical, "Workbook not open"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' check worksheets
        msg = ""
        bOK = False
        For Each ws In Workbooks(sOPEXwbk).Sheets
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & ws.Name
            If ws.Name = sOPEXsht Then bOK = True
        Next
        
        ' worksheet not found
        If bOK = False Then
            MsgBox "'" & sOPEXsht & "' not in list" & msg, vbCritical, "Sheet Not Found"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            ' OK
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A42") = Workbooks(sOPEXwbk).Sheets(sOPEXsht).Range("B22").Value
            MsgBox "Copied B22 from " & sOPEXwbk & " Sheet " & sOPEXsht, vbInformation
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I've run into a few complications with this code.

Comment: 1. In your code you mention the input workbook is sOPEXwbk but if I were to create this workbook the extension is ".xlsx". In that case the period interferes with the syntax. Is there any workaround for this? Thank you so much! @CDP1802

Comment: @niCE "interferes with the syntax" on which line ?  You are entering the workbook name e.g "myworkbook.xlsx" in cell A37, the code does not need to change. If you are getting an error single step the program using the debug->F8 and let me know the error message and line number.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, you're right there's no error (Besides needing an additional "End If" at the end)? I only bring that up because when I run the code I don't get any errors, but B22's value doesn't appear in A42 in "This workbook" or vice versa. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but do you have any idea as to what it is? Thank you so much once again, this is so helpful!

Comment: (not sure if I need this for you to see the comment)

Comment: @nICE you shouldn't have needed to add end if. Did you copy / paste my code? Did you get a message box ?

Comment: That's so strange. I was typing it in before because it's on another laptop. But I went in and copied it and it worked...Thank you so much. You have no idea how much this helps!!!